# How to getcomponent using FindGameObjecstWithTag>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I am building a multiplayer game using unity. The main player is a prefab spawned using network manager and contains **Player** tag and the. Down below is the enemy attack script that searches of **Player** tag but in multiplayer get only one **Player** in return.How can i alter it so that the Gameobject player is an array and playerHealth can getcomponent PlayerHealth.

```
public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;     // The time in seconds between each attack.
    public int attackDamage = 10;               // The amount of health taken away per attack.


    Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator component.
    GameObject player;                          // Reference to the player GameObject.
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;                  // Reference to the player's health.
    EnemyHealth enemyHealth;                    // Reference to this enemy's health.
    bool playerInRange;                         // Whether player is within the trigger collider and can be attacked.
    float timer;                                // Timer for counting up to the next attack.


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
        enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        // If the entering collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is in range.
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }


    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        // If the exiting collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is no longer in range.
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        // If the timer exceeds the time between attacks, the player is in range and this enemy is alive...
        if(timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange && enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        {
            // ... attack.
            Attack ();
        }

        // If the player has zero or less health...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // ... tell the animator the player is dead.
            anim.SetTrigger ("PlayerDead");
        }
    }


    void Attack ()
    {
        // Reset the timer.
        timer = 0f;

        // If the player has health to lose...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        {
            // ... damage the player.
            playerHealth.TakeDamage (attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to store multiple player objects and multiple player health references? Have you tried using `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` and...iterating through the result?

Comment: I tried it but was not helpful gave an error **'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'GetComponent'**

Comment: How do you plan on using multiple players/healths with your current script? Provided you do store all of them in a collection, how will you identify which one is being affected by `Attack ()`? Can the enemy attack all the players in range at the same time? Or does it have to choose one? I feel in its current state, the scope of this question is more than just properly retrieving and storing a collection of players - you're going to need a rework of your game logic as well afterwards.

Comment: Yes the enemy attack all the players at same time. I have a different script to spawn the enemy and a different one to move towards the enemy

Comment: You may want to consider having the players handle the logic of whether they're dead or not - in terms of responsibilities, this seems like something that the enemy shouldn't have to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You should need to use   [**FindGameObjectsWithTag**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) with [**invoke repeating**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html). A untested code snippet given below:

public GameObject[] playersList;

```
void Start() {
          //Invokes the method methodName in time seconds,
          //then repeatedly every repeatRate seconds.
          InvokeRepeating("CheckPlayers", 2.0f, 0.3f);
    }


public void CheckPlayers(){
       //assign player in the player list
       playersList= GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Player");
      //now playersList contains all player, do what you want with it

}
```